# Spacy ValueError [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents while creating custom NER

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

As I am new to spacy, i am stuck with one problem statement. Read a lot of articles but doesn't help. I am constantly getting "[E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: ". My code looks like this :

```
train_data = ('We report the use of pamidronate for acute, severe hypercalcemia secondary to iatrogenic vitamin D poisoning.', {'entities': [(328, 348, 'ADE'), (373, 382, 'DRUG')]}), ('We report the use of pamidronate for acute, severe hypercalcemia secondary to iatrogenic vitamin D poisoning.', {'entities': [(373, 392, 'ADE'), (373, 382, 'DRUG')]})

for text,annotation in train_data:
  for ent in annotation.get('entities'):
    ner.add_label(ent[2])

disable_pipes =[pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']

with nlp.disable_pipes(*disable_pipes):
    #nlp.vocab.vectors.name = 'spacy_model' # without this, spaCy throws an "unnamed" error
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    
    for itr in range(100):
        
        try:
        
            random.shuffle(train_data) # shuffle the training data before each iteration
            losses = {}
            
            batches = minibatch(train_data, size = compounding(16.0, 64.0, 1.5))

            for batch in batches:
                
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                
                nlp.update(          
                    texts,
                    annotations,
                    drop = 0.5,  
                    sgd = optimizer,
                    losses = losses)
            
            print('Interation = '+str(itr))
            print('Losses = '+str(losses))
        
        except ValueError as ve:
            
            print(ve)
```

[E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(373, 392, 'ADE')' and '(373, 382, 'DRUG')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.

Please help me with how can I get this error sorted. If I need to remove this kind of record from training data then it is a huge number. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Just a suggestion: have you tried to look/ask in their issue page on Github? They are usually very responsive

Comment: Yes, I did but no help from there. It seems that most of the time the issue is still not resolved.

Comment: Can you link to your issue on the spaCy Github page?

Answer (score 1):

> [E103] Trying to set conflicting doc.ents: '(373, 392, 'ADE')' and '(373, 382, 'DRUG')'. A token can only be part of one entity, so make sure the entities you're setting don't overlap.

The numbers here are character offsets. So at `text[373:392]` you have some kind of text and you're labelling it as ADE. But you're also trying to label `text[373:382]` as a DRUG.

Those texts overlap, so you're trying to give the same word multiple labels, and you can't do that. Like the error text says, a token can only be part of one entity.

Since your annotations start at exactly the same character (373), either they were made for a system that supports overlapping annotations (which spaCy does not), or something is wrong.

There are NER systems that support overlapping or nested annotations, but most do not, so I suspect this is some issue with your annotations. Either way, you need to look at the text with the annotation and see if the annotation is right. If it's not right you need to fix the data. If it is correct, but it uses overlapping annotations, you need to decide how you want to handle that. Maybe you want to keep all DRUG annotations but throw out ADE annotations. It really depends on your goals and application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know the issue is with annotation but how do I handle it. I want to keep the ADE and get rid of the DRUG. I am also struggling to get that in code. Please help me in with the same

Comment: How to filter your annotations depends on their format, but it should be pretty simple. If they're just a list it would be like `annotations = [aa for aa in annotations if aa["label"] != "DRUG"]`. If that doesn't work open a new question. Also, if my answer was helpful please upvote it with the up arrow and accept with the big check mark.